# How to save keys and other paras in HElib

Tags: homomorphic-encryption

Recently I'm using HElib for project. Here I hope to init a Client-class,which has pub&pri keys. However when I was building class, I found that I don't know how to save Keys and other paras like Context. The code I use is "example" of HElib. Could someone who is familiar with HElib tell me more about saving in HElibs, thank you very much.

Comment: As far as I remember there was an export function for that.

Comment: Thanks for your help sir, could you tell me more about it? I didn't find such functions in HElib's documentation page.

Comment: Did you read the sample codes?

Comment: I've read three files in "examples" and now I'm reading files in "tests", did I miss something?